# Changing background of a row for a matrix in ssrs 2008 not working properly

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a matrix in ssrs 2008 like below:

[image]

What I want is to change background color of the 1st and the 4th rows. To provide this, I added the code below to the report:

```
Function AlternateColor(Byval rowNumber as integer) As String
Dim blue As String = "LightBlue"
Dim plum As String = "Plum"
Dim white As String = "White"

If rowNumber = 1 then 
    Return blue
Else if rowNumber = 4 then
    Return plum
Else
    Return white
End If
End Function
```

And I added this line as the background color expression for each cells including Fields!.Value:

```
=Code.AlternateColor(rownumber(nothing))
```

After all, this is an example from the result:

[image]

This is the first row, and I was expecting the see it all blue, and the 4th row all plum, the others should be all white. Changing `rownumber("Tablix14")` in the expression did not help as well, where matrix's name is Tablix14. Any help regarding to fix the issue here would be so appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It seems the you are passing a different rownumber for each AlternateColor function call in the same row. Note RowNumber() function could be returning different values in the same row of a matrix.

Comment: What should I use instead to fix it then:(

Comment: Maybe you can calculate in your query a column that lets you set the color in SSRS, what is the expression used for the row group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the expression as below fixed the issue.

```
=Code.AlternateColor(Runningvalue(Fields!FiscalQuarter.Value,CountDistinct,"Tablix14"))
```